# AngularJs and chart

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-chart

I'm trying to create charts with [**angular-chart**](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/). Then I followed the steps and requirement needed as related in docs, but my canvas tag doesn't render anything.

**HTML**

My Layout HTML:

`<div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <section class="content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </div>`

My Index.html

`<div ui-view="Content">
</div>`

My Nested View

`<head>
    <title></title>
        <script src="~/Content/chartjs/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/chartjs/angular-chart.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/chartjs/angular-chart.css" /></head>
<body ng-controller="RecordCtrl">
    <div class="panel-body" ng-show="true">
        <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"></canvas>
    </div>`

**app.js:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngMaterial','chart.js']);
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
$scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
```

I think I've done the steps required in the link, however I still got:

[image]

Comment: Where do you get the `labels` and `data` from? Is it via Ajax or is it a static JSON in your controller?

Comment: Do you also put the reference to Angular.js ?

Comment: Did you inject chart.js to your module? angular.module('myModule', ['chart.js']);

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, so please post the full controller and html.

Comment: And make sure you've added `'chart.js'` the the dependencies list in your app's module. It's super important

Comment: @AlonEitan i got from the static Json in my Controller

Comment: So please check what me and @marton wrote about including the dependency of `chart.js` in your module

Comment: @AlonEitan there in my recent edit, i include chart.js dependency in my app.js

Comment: @IanOctoBear And where's `angular.js`? should be above `/Content/chartjs/angular-chart.js"`

Comment: @IanOctoBear I recommend that you install [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) so you'll know when you have JS errors

Comment: i put angular.js in my layout page. Chart is a nested view inside layout page @AlonEitan

Comment: I already install it, but no errors are shown but yet my canvas still show blank white space @AlonEitan

Comment: No, you can't load dependencies like that. (You can do it with `requirejs` though). Try putting all the `*.js`s in the layout page

Comment: how can i do that ? @AlonEitan

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shammelburg/hsyhmgc9/9/).

Please make sure you are referencing the correct `chart.js` version 1.1.1
[Chart.js v1.1.1](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chart.js/1.1.1/Chart.min.js)

and

[angular-chart.js v0.8.8](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/0.8.8/angular-chart.js) these are the latest of each and works in my JSFiddle.

Comment: Appreciate it man.. But Still not working :( Should i reference angular-chart.min.css ?

Comment: @Ian OctoBear, yes do reference the css file.